# What are the possible parameters of DoVerb function for Excel server application?

Tags: excel, vba, powerbuilder, ole

Is there some way to get help on what numbers will perform what actions when DoVerb() function is called for Excel Server Application in PowerBuilder?

The VBA help on microsoft site does not explain that detail https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/office-shared-vba/articles/getting-started-with-vba-in-office

Comment: There is a way to get detail for numbers passed to Doverb() function. https://m.blog.naver.com/PostView.nhn?blogId=iooic2&logNo=44904709&proxyReferer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bing.com%2F and another link is there that explains almost same technique https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20248344/Merging-data-from-PB-with-a-Word-Template.html

Comment: Further detail is available on Appeon https://community.appeon.com/groups/powerbuilder/ole-extending-capabilities-powerbuilder-part-1